# get data-price of selected value in dropdown in a array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have following code

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:40%">
            <select id="pname.0" name="pname[]" class="form-control ">
            <?php 
            $this->db->order_by('name','asc');
            $prod = $this->db->get('product')->result_array();
            foreach($prod as $row):  ?>
                <option  data-price="<?php echo $row['price'];?>" value="<?php echo $row['prod_id'];?>" >
                    <?php echo ucwords($row['name']);?> 
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td style="width:10%">
            <input class="form-control" onchange="javascript:calc();" id="item_quantity.0" name="qnty[]" value=""/>
        </td>
        <td class="text-right" style="width:10%">
            <input class="form-control text-right" onchange="javascript:calc();" id="item_price.0" name="price[]" value=""/>
        </td>                   
        <td class="text-right" style="width:10%">
            <input class="form-control text-right" id="subtot.0" readonly name="item_sub_total" value=""/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Now I want to get the value of `data-price` attribute of selected option on change in Dropdown to the textbox having dynamic id `item_price_`0. This is changing as I have added the add row button. When I click on Add row, the id will become `item_price_`1.

Kindly help me how can I get these value using jquery or javascript

Comment: you want the same selected value in multiple text boxes?

Comment: @LShetty, No i want the selected value in respective text box in the same row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you were after?

```
//if your table has an id or class, use it as tag selector is not good without context.
//$(".tableClass") OR $("#tableID")    
$("table").on('change', "select[id^='pname']", function() {

    var $row = $(this).closest("tr"); 
    $row.find("input[id^='item_price']").val( $(this).find('option:selected').data("price") );

});
```

So, to use `.` in selectors, you need to escape them as mentioned (2nd para) in [jQuery selectors API](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Demo@[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/98vn1j5o/2/)

Comment: @LSheety, I tried your code, it works for only id pname.0 but I want it be dynamic because it;s never the same. It is changing pname.0, pname.1, pname.2 etc.

Comment: So, you should be more clear about your question! Do you have multiple rows with select and input?

Comment: Yes, I have multiple rows with select & input having id incrementer

Comment: Kindly help me LShetty, because your answer is almost what I want

Answer (score 0):

First assign a class to all `select`. (in addition to "form-control"). I suppose selects have `test` class

```
 var selectedPrices = [];
    var i = 0;
    $(".test").each(function(){
       selectedPrices[i] = $(this).find(":selected").attr("data-price");
    i++;
    });
```

Now, `selectedPrices` is an array of prices. You can do anything you want with it.

Comment: select field have also dynamic id like pname.0, pname.1 etc.

Comment: I tried but no success, also tell me how to get the value of selectedPrices in my textbox

Comment: You forgot to increment `i`.  Add `i++` inside `each()` loop

Answer (score 0):

You can listen the change on your element, and get the price attribute like so:

```
$('#pname.0').on('change', function(){
    var price = $(this).find('option:selected').data('price');
});
```

PS: I'm not sure you can use "." in ID attribute.